# What happens when a computer is offline and a WebClient makes a request?

Tags: c#, webclient

What happens when I make a request with a WebClient object when the computer is offline? Is there a way to detect that beforehand. or should I be handling some sort of exception?

Comment: Catch the exception, its easier than trying to do detection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WebException will be thrown.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception(v=vs.80).aspx